# Creating a internal standard load balancer with HA ports in Azure

Tags: azure, internal-load-balancer

I am trying to create a internal standard load balancer in Azure with HA ports using ARM template . I am getting below validation error.

{
"code": "InvalidTemplateDeployment",
"details": [
{
"code": "PortValueIsOutOfRange",
"message": "Resource DC10TESTCPW01 has invalid value of Port (0). The value must be between 1 and 65535.",
"details": []
}
],
"message": "The template deployment 'Microsoft.Template-20210524012843' is not valid according to the validation procedure. The tracking id is '585f5d57-4423-47a8-a45d-4a0e371b47c2'. See inner errors for details."
}

Answer (score 0):

Sample:

```
{
  "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2019-04-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
  "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
  "parameters": {
    "adminUsername": {
      "type": "string",
      "metadata": {
        "description": "Admin username"
      }
    },
    "adminPassword": {
      "type": "securestring",
      "metadata": {
        "description": "Admin password"
      }
    },
    "vmNamePrefix": {
      "type": "string",
      "defaultValue": "BackendVM",
      "metadata": {
        "description": "Prefix to use for VM names"
      }
    },
    "location": {
      "type": "string",
      "defaultValue": "[resourceGroup().location]",
      "metadata": {
        "description": "Location for all resources."
      }
    },
    "vmSize": {
      "type": "string",
      "defaultValue": "Standard_DS1_V2",
      "metadata": {
        "description": "Size of the virtual machines"
      }
    }
  },
  "variables": {
    "availabilitySetName": "AvSet",
    "storageAccountType": "Standard_LRS",
    "storageAccountName": "[uniqueString(resourceGroup().id)]",
    "virtualNetworkName": "vNet",
    "subnetName": "backendSubnet",
    "loadBalancerName": "ilb",
    "networkInterfaceName": "nic",
    "subnetRef": "[resourceId('Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/subnets', variables('virtualNetworkName'), variables('subnetName'))]",
    "numberOfInstances": 2
  },
  "resources": [
    {
      "type": "Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts",
      "apiVersion": "2019-06-01",
      "name": "[variables('storageAccountName')]",
      "location": "[parameters('location')]",
      "sku": {
        "name": "[variables('storageAccountType')]"
      },
      "kind": "StorageV2"
    },
    {
      "type": "Microsoft.Compute/availabilitySets",
      "apiVersion": "2020-06-01",
      "name": "[variables('availabilitySetName')]",
      "location": "[parameters('location')]",
      "sku": {
        "name": "Aligned"
      },
      "properties": {
        "PlatformUpdateDomainCount": 2,
        "PlatformFaultDomainCount": 2
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks",
      "apiVersion": "2020-06-01",
      "name": "[variables('virtualNetworkName')]",
      "location": "[parameters('location')]",
      "properties": {
        "addressSpace": {
          "addressPrefixes": [
            "10.0.0.0/16"
          ]
        },
        "subnets": [
          {
            "name": "[variables('subnetName')]",
            "properties": {
              "addressPrefix": "10.0.2.0/24"
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "Microsoft.Network/networkInterfaces",
      "apiVersion": "2020-06-01",
      "name": "[concat(variables('networkInterfaceName'), copyindex())]",
      "location": "[parameters('location')]",
      "copy": {
        "name": "nicLoop",
        "count": "[variables('numberOfInstances')]"
      },
      "dependsOn": [
        "[variables('virtualNetworkName')]",
        "[variables('loadBalancerName')]"
      ],
      "properties": {
        "ipConfigurations": [
          {
            "name": "ipconfig1",
            "properties": {
              "privateIPAllocationMethod": "Dynamic",
              "subnet": {
                "id": "[variables('subnetRef')]"
              },
              "loadBalancerBackendAddressPools": [
                {
                  "id": "[resourceId('Microsoft.Network/loadBalancers/backendAddressPools', variables('loadBalancerName'), 'BackendPool1')]"
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "Microsoft.Network/loadBalancers",
      "apiVersion": "2020-06-01",
      "name": "[variables('loadBalancerName')]",
      "location": "[parameters('location')]",
      "sku": {
        "name": "Standard"
      },
      "dependsOn": [
        "[variables('virtualNetworkName')]"
      ],
      "properties": {
        "frontendIPConfigurations": [
          {
            "properties": {
              "subnet": {
                "id": "[variables('subnetRef')]"
              },
              "privateIPAddress": "10.0.2.6",
              "privateIPAllocationMethod": "Static"
            },
            "name": "LoadBalancerFrontend"
          }
        ],
        "backendAddressPools": [
          {
            "name": "BackendPool1"
          }
        ],
        "loadBalancingRules": [
          {
            "properties": {
              "frontendIPConfiguration": {
                "id": "[resourceId('Microsoft.Network/loadBalancers/frontendIpConfigurations', variables('loadBalancerName'), 'LoadBalancerFrontend')]"
              },
              "backendAddressPool": {
                "id": "[resourceId('Microsoft.Network/loadBalancers/backendAddressPools', variables('loadBalancerName'), 'BackendPool1')]"
              },
              "probe": {
                "id": "[resourceId('Microsoft.Network/loadBalancers/probes', variables('loadBalancerName'), 'lbprobe')]"
              },
              "protocol": "Tcp",
              "frontendPort": 80,
              "backendPort": 80,
              "idleTimeoutInMinutes": 15
            },
            "Name": "lbrule"
          }
        ],
        "probes": [
          {
            "properties": {
              "protocol": "Tcp",
              "port": 80,
              "intervalInSeconds": 15,
              "numberOfProbes": 2
            },
            "name": "lbprobe"
          }
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines",
      "apiVersion": "2020-06-01",
      "name": "[concat(parameters('vmNamePrefix'), copyindex())]",
      "location": "[parameters('location')]",
      "copy": {
        "name": "virtualMachineLoop",
        "count": "[variables('numberOfInstances')]"
      },
      "dependsOn": [
        "[variables('storageAccountName')]",
        "nicLoop",
        "[variables('availabilitySetName')]"
      ],
      "properties": {
        "availabilitySet": {
          "id": "[resourceId('Microsoft.Compute/availabilitySets',variables('availabilitySetName'))]"
        },
        "hardwareProfile": {
          "vmSize": "[parameters('vmSize')]"
        },
        "osProfile": {
          "computerName": "[concat(parameters('vmNamePrefix'), copyIndex())]",
          "adminUsername": "[parameters('adminUsername')]",
          "adminPassword": "[parameters('adminPassword')]"
        },
        "storageProfile": {
          "imageReference": {
            "publisher": "MicrosoftWindowsServer",
            "offer": "WindowsServer",
            "sku": "2019-Datacenter",
            "version": "latest"
          },
          "osDisk": {
            "createOption": "FromImage"
          }
        },
        "networkProfile": {
          "networkInterfaces": [
            {
              "id": "[resourceId('Microsoft.Network/networkInterfaces', concat(variables('networkInterfaceName'), copyindex()))]"
            }
          ]
        },
        "diagnosticsProfile": {
          "bootDiagnostics": {
            "enabled": true,
            "storageUri": "[reference(variables('storageAccountName')).primaryEndpoints.blob]"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Update with HA:

1. Configure more than one front-end private IP address for a single
   internal Standard Load Balancer resource.
2. Configure multipleload-balancing rules, where each rule has a single unique front-end IP address selected.
3. Select the HA ports option, and then set Floating IP to Enabled for all the load-balancing rules.

**JSON View**:

```
{
    "name": "ilb1",
    "id": "/subscriptions/<SubscriptionId>/resourceGroups/<RG>/providers/Microsoft.Network/loadBalancers/ilb1",
    "etag": "W/\"<ETAG>\"",
    "type": "Microsoft.Network/loadBalancers",
    "location": "westeurope",
    "tags": {},
    "properties": {
        "provisioningState": "Succeeded",
        "resourceGuid": "<ResourceGuid>",
        "frontendIPConfigurations": [
            {
                "name": "LoadBalancerFrontEnd",
                "id": "/subscriptions/<SubscriptionId>/resourceGroups/<RG>/providers/Microsoft.Network/loadBalancers/ilb1/frontendIPConfigurations/LoadBalancerFrontEnd",
                "etag": "W/\"<ETAG>\"",
                "type": "Microsoft.Network/loadBalancers/frontendIPConfigurations",
                "properties": {
                    "provisioningState": "Succeeded",
                    "privateIPAddress": "10.0.0.6",
                    "privateIPAllocationMethod": "Static",
                    "subnet": {
                        "id": "/subscriptions/<SubscriptionId>/resourceGroups/<RG>/providers/Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/<RG>-vnet/subnets/default"
                    },
                    "loadBalancingRules": [
                        {
                            "id": "/subscriptions/<SubscriptionId>/resourceGroups/<RG>/providers/Microsoft.Network/loadBalancers/ilb1/loadBalancingRules/rule1"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            },
            {
                "name": "ilbIP2",
                "id": "/subscriptions/<SubscriptionId>/resourceGroups/<RG>/providers/Microsoft.Network/loadBalancers/ilb1/frontendIPConfigurations/ilbIP2",
                "etag": "W/\"<ETAG>\"",
                "type": "Microsoft.Network/loadBalancers/frontendIPConfigurations",
                "properties": {
                    "provisioningState": "Succeeded",
                    "privateIPAddress": "10.0.0.7",
                    "privateIPAllocationMethod": "Static",
                    "subnet": {
                        "id": "/subscriptions/<SubscriptionId>/resourceGroups/<RG>/providers/Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/<RG>-vnet/subnets/default"
                    },
                    "loadBalancingRules": [
                        {
                            "id": "/subscriptions/<SubscriptionId>/resourceGroups/<RG>/providers/Microsoft.Network/loadBalancers/ilb1/loadBalancingRules/rule2"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            }
        ],
        "backendAddressPools": [
            {
                "name": "poolbackend1",
                "id": "/subscriptions/<SubscriptionId>/resourceGroups/<RG>/providers/Microsoft.Network/loadBalancers/ilb1/backendAddressPools/poolbackend1",
                "etag": "W/\"<ETAG>\"",
                "properties": {
                    "provisioningState": "Succeeded",
                    "loadBalancingRules": [
                        {
                            "id": "/subscriptions/<SubscriptionId>/resourceGroups/<RG>/providers/Microsoft.Network/loadBalancers/ilb1/loadBalancingRules/rule1"
                        },
                        {
                            "id": "/subscriptions/<SubscriptionId>/resourceGroups/<RG>/providers/Microsoft.Network/loadBalancers/ilb1/loadBalancingRules/rule2"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                "type": "Microsoft.Network/loadBalancers/backendAddressPools"
            }
        ],
        "loadBalancingRules": [
            {
                "name": "rule1",
                "id": "/subscriptions/<SubscriptionId>/resourceGroups/<RG>/providers/Microsoft.Network/loadBalancers/ilb1/loadBalancingRules/rule1",
                "etag": "W/\"<ETAG>\"",
                "type": "Microsoft.Network/loadBalancers/loadBalancingRules",
                "properties": {
                    "provisioningState": "Succeeded",
                    "frontendIPConfiguration": {
                        "id": "/subscriptions/<SubscriptionId>/resourceGroups/<RG>/providers/Microsoft.Network/loadBalancers/ilb1/frontendIPConfigurations/LoadBalancerFrontEnd"
                    },
                    "frontendPort": 0,
                    "backendPort": 0,
                    "enableFloatingIP": true,
                    "idleTimeoutInMinutes": 4,
                    "protocol": "All",
                    "loadDistribution": "SourceIP",
                    "disableOutboundSnat": true,
                    "backendAddressPool": {
                        "id": "/subscriptions/<SubscriptionId>/resourceGroups/<RG>/providers/Microsoft.Network/loadBalancers/ilb1/backendAddressPools/poolbackend1"
                    },
                    "probe": {
                        "id": "/subscriptions/<SubscriptionId>/resourceGroups/<RG>/providers/Microsoft.Network/loadBalancers/ilb1/probes/Hprobe1"
                    }
                }
            },
            {
                "name": "rule2",
                "id": "/subscriptions/<SubscriptionId>/resourceGroups/<RG>/providers/Microsoft.Network/loadBalancers/ilb1/loadBalancingRules/rule2",
                "etag": "W/\"<ETAG>\"",
                "type": "Microsoft.Network/loadBalancers/loadBalancingRules",
                "properties": {
                    "provisioningState": "Succeeded",
                    "frontendIPConfiguration": {
                        "id": "/subscriptions/<SubscriptionId>/resourceGroups/<RG>/providers/Microsoft.Network/loadBalancers/ilb1/frontendIPConfigurations/ilbIP2"
                    },
                    "frontendPort": 0,
                    "backendPort": 0,
                    "enableFloatingIP": true,
                    "idleTimeoutInMinutes": 4,
                    "protocol": "All",
                    "loadDistribution": "SourceIP",
                    "disableOutboundSnat": true,
                    "backendAddressPool": {
                        "id": "/subscriptions/<SubscriptionId>/resourceGroups/<RG>/providers/Microsoft.Network/loadBalancers/ilb1/backendAddressPools/poolbackend1"
                    },
                    "probe": {
                        "id": "/subscriptions/<SubscriptionId>/resourceGroups/<RG>/providers/Microsoft.Network/loadBalancers/ilb1/probes/Hprobe1"
                    }
                }
            }
        ],
        "probes": [
            {
                "name": "Hprobe1",
                "id": "/subscriptions/<SubscriptionId>/resourceGroups/<RG>/providers/Microsoft.Network/loadBalancers/ilb1/probes/Hprobe1",
                "etag": "W/\"<ETAG>\"",
                "properties": {
                    "provisioningState": "Succeeded",
                    "protocol": "Tcp",
                    "port": 80,
                    "intervalInSeconds": 5,
                    "numberOfProbes": 2,
                    "loadBalancingRules": [
                        {
                            "id": "/subscriptions/<SubscriptionId>/resourceGroups/<RG>/providers/Microsoft.Network/loadBalancers/ilb1/loadBalancingRules/rule1"
                        },
                        {
                            "id": "/subscriptions/<SubscriptionId>/resourceGroups/<RG>/providers/Microsoft.Network/loadBalancers/ilb1/loadBalancingRules/rule2"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                "type": "Microsoft.Network/loadBalancers/probes"
            }
        ],
        "inboundNatRules": [],
        "inboundNatPools": []
    },
    "sku": {
        "name": "Standard"
    }
}
```

**ILB HA Template**:

```
{
    "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2019-04-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
    "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
    "parameters": {
        "loadBalancers_ilb1_name": {
            "defaultValue": "ilb1",
            "type": "String"
        },
        "virtualNetworks_<RG>_vnet_externalid": {
            "defaultValue": "/subscriptions/<subscriptionId>/resourceGroups/<RG>/providers/Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/<RG>-vnet",
            "type": "String"
        }
    },
    "variables": {},
    "resources": [
        {
            "type": "Microsoft.Network/loadBalancers",
            "apiVersion": "2020-11-01",
            "name": "[parameters('loadBalancers_ilb1_name')]",
            "location": "westeurope",
            "dependsOn": [
                "[resourceId('Microsoft.Network/loadBalancers/backendAddressPools', parameters('loadBalancers_ilb1_name'), 'poolbackend1')]"
            ],
            "sku": {
                "name": "Standard",
                "tier": "Regional"
            },
            "properties": {
                "frontendIPConfigurations": [
                    {
                        "name": "LoadBalancerFrontEnd",
                        "properties": {
                            "privateIPAddress": "10.0.0.6",
                            "privateIPAllocationMethod": "Static",
                            "subnet": {
                                "id": "[concat(parameters('virtualNetworks_<RG>_vnet_externalid'), '/subnets/default')]"
                            },
                            "privateIPAddressVersion": "IPv4"
                        },
                        "zones": [
                            "1",
                            "2",
                            "3"
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "ilbIP2",
                        "properties": {
                            "privateIPAddress": "10.0.0.7",
                            "privateIPAllocationMethod": "Static",
                            "subnet": {
                                "id": "[concat(parameters('virtualNetworks_<RG>_vnet_externalid'), '/subnets/default')]"
                            },
                            "privateIPAddressVersion": "IPv4"
                        },
                        "zones": [
                            "1",
                            "2",
                            "3"
                        ]
                    }
                ],
                "backendAddressPools": [
                    {
                        "name": "poolbackend1",
                        "properties": {
                            "loadBalancerBackendAddresses": [
                                {
                                    "name": "1a959793-169e-4e7f-8711-128f237dbf67",
                                    "properties": {
                                        "ipAddress": "10.0.0.9",
                                        "virtualNetwork": {
                                            "id": "[parameters('virtualNetworks_<RG>_vnet_externalid')]"
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    }
                ],
                "loadBalancingRules": [
                    {
                        "name": "rule1",
                        "properties": {
                            "frontendIPConfiguration": {
                                "id": "[concat(resourceId('Microsoft.Network/loadBalancers', parameters('loadBalancers_ilb1_name')), '/frontendIPConfigurations/LoadBalancerFrontEnd')]"
                            },
                            "frontendPort": 0,
                            "backendPort": 0,
                            "enableFloatingIP": true,
                            "idleTimeoutInMinutes": 4,
                            "protocol": "All",
                            "enableTcpReset": false,
                            "loadDistribution": "SourceIP",
                            "disableOutboundSnat": true,
                            "backendAddressPool": {
                                "id": "[resourceId('Microsoft.Network/loadBalancers/backendAddressPools', parameters('loadBalancers_ilb1_name'), 'poolbackend1')]"
                            },
                            "probe": {
                                "id": "[concat(resourceId('Microsoft.Network/loadBalancers', parameters('loadBalancers_ilb1_name')), '/probes/Hprobe1')]"
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "rule2",
                        "properties": {
                            "frontendIPConfiguration": {
                                "id": "[concat(resourceId('Microsoft.Network/loadBalancers', parameters('loadBalancers_ilb1_name')), '/frontendIPConfigurations/ilbIP2')]"
                            },
                            "frontendPort": 0,
                            "backendPort": 0,
                            "enableFloatingIP": true,
                            "idleTimeoutInMinutes": 4,
                            "protocol": "All",
                            "enableTcpReset": false,
                            "loadDistribution": "SourceIP",
                            "disableOutboundSnat": true,
                            "backendAddressPool": {
                                "id": "[resourceId('Microsoft.Network/loadBalancers/backendAddressPools', parameters('loadBalancers_ilb1_name'), 'poolbackend1')]"
                            },
                            "probe": {
                                "id": "[concat(resourceId('Microsoft.Network/loadBalancers', parameters('loadBalancers_ilb1_name')), '/probes/Hprobe1')]"
                            }
                        }
                    }
                ],
                "probes": [
                    {
                        "name": "Hprobe1",
                        "properties": {
                            "protocol": "Tcp",
                            "port": 80,
                            "intervalInSeconds": 5,
                            "numberOfProbes": 2
                        }
                    }
                ],
                "inboundNatRules": [],
                "outboundRules": [],
                "inboundNatPools": []
            }
        },
        {
            "type": "Microsoft.Network/loadBalancers/backendAddressPools",
            "apiVersion": "2020-11-01",
            "name": "[concat(parameters('loadBalancers_ilb1_name'), '/poolbackend1')]",
            "dependsOn": [
                "[resourceId('Microsoft.Network/loadBalancers', parameters('loadBalancers_ilb1_name'))]"
            ],
            "properties": {
                "loadBalancerBackendAddresses": [
                    {
                        "name": "1a959793-169e-4e7f-8711-128f237dbf67",
                        "properties": {
                            "ipAddress": "10.0.0.9",
                            "virtualNetwork": {
                                "id": "[parameters('virtualNetworks_<RG>_vnet_externalid')]"
                            }
                        }
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Thanks for responding but i want to create load balancer with HA ports

Comment: Updated answer.